Unable to cast List<T> to a class that is derived from List<T>
I have derived a class "ListOfT" from List<T> to have a place to put function that operate on a list of T.
I have a function that iterates over the list and should return a sub-list of T using Linq:
public class ListOfT : List<T> 
{
  //no explicit constructor
  //other functions to work on this list of T's ...

  public ListOfT GenerateSubList()
  {
    return this.Where(t => t.SomeCriteria).ToList(); // <- compiler will complain

    return (ListOfT) this.Where(t => t.SomeCriteria).ToList(); // <- compiler is ok, but I get a runtime error
  }
}

The compiler now complains that it can't cast List<T> to ListOfT. Obviously the call to "ToList()" will generate a new List<T>, but I would like to have something that creates an Instance of ListOfT.
I have tried an explicit cast (which will pacify the compiler), but that will lead to a runtime error.
Is there an elegant way to perform this cast (or replace the ToList() call)?

Solution (see @SomeBody's answer):
Thank you all for your kind comments and proposed solutions. Instead of commenting on each of them I will try to summarize it here:
public class ListOfT : List<T> 
{
  //public constructor
  public ListOfT() {}

  //hidden constructor to create a ListOfT from an enumerable
  private ListOfT(IEnumerable<T> subList) 
            : base(subList) { }
  
  public ListOfT GenerateSubList()
  {
    //using linq to create an enumerator that gets 
    //passed to the hidden constructor
    return new ListOfT(this.Where(t => t.SomeCriteria));
  }
}

Maybe I should have used SomeClass instead of T in my question to clarify that the ListOfT class is a concrete instance of List<T> using SomeClass as T, not a template class in itself.
@Tim Schmelter: The t.SomeCriteria part was to indicate that each instance of T contained in the list has a property that I want to test to have it included in the sub list. Thanks for the link to Why not to inherit from List<T>, i was reading through it while waiting for answers. See my comments below regarding the "has" vs. "is".
Also (@Rookie), yes, the new list returned by GenerateSubList() will not contain copies of the original elements, but references to the original T's stored in the instance of ListOfT I call the GenerateSubList() on. This is intended.
@Oren Tamam and @Fildor: I did not go down the "has" route instead of "Is", as this would have required me to implement the IList<T> interface. As @Tim mentioned above, there is a lengthy discussion as to why not to use classes derived from List<T>. Personally, I think it is a nice way to have functions that operate on a certain type of list in one place. In my opinion, the difference between has and is boils down to a personal choice and the scenario you are using it in.
@Ralf mentioned extension methods as another way to "enhance" a concrete type of list. I have used them in some places where I had a class hierarchy where each descendant needed to be "listed". In that case, the static class containing the extensions was a nice way to have all list-related functions of my zoo of classes in one place.

You might want to take a look at Extension methods. You can't do such a cast as a List is not a ListOfT.  YOu need to implement your own method to create a ListOfT from whats returned by Where.

"I have derived a class "ListOfT" from List" - that's really not recommended in the first place. And you also don't need to. With that simple filter you cannot get anything different from a T-Generic (List, IList or IEnumerable ... or T)

Maybe, if you go into more detail on what it is that you are trying to do, we can lead you a way...

" I did not go down the "has" route instead of "Is"" - I never said you should. I said tell us what you are trying to do, because I think you are completely off track.

^^ https://dotnetfiddle.net/2t8WCL (Note last example, especially)

Don't put the answer into the question. You can't answer your own question below.

@Charlieface I put the solution I used into the question because the anwer below was not exactly what I was looking for (though close enough to get me on track).
Not sure what the recommended procedure is in these places would be if I can't answer my own question ...

Can somone explain why my question received two downvotes?

You can answer your own question. Just go to the box below and type your answer in, and click Post Your Answer. The question is supposed to be just a question, not both.

There is a constructor in List<T> which accepts an IEnumerable<T>. You can call this from your subclass:
public class MyList<T> : List<T>
{
    public MyList()
    {
    }

    private MyList(IEnumerable<T> items)
    : base(items)
    {
    }

    public MyList<T> GenerateSubList()
    {
        return new MyList<T>(this.Where(t => t.SomeCriteria));
    }
}

Of course, you can also make the constructor public if you want to use it from outside your class.
Online-demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/RxBMr0

I wonder what SomeCriteria is without a type constraint on T. The whole requirement is unclear. Apart from that you should link this: Why not inherit from List

Thank you @SomeBody, introducing the additional constructor (and the public default to be able to construct an instance of 'ListOfT') did the trick.

I don't understand the downvotes on this answer. The only reason I can think of is that this example uses public class MyList<T> : List<T> instead of public class MyList : List<T> (as I have done in the solution posted in my edited answer).
It would be nice if the downvoter would comment on why they think this answer is wrong.

The List returned by ToList() is a new instance that extracts a specific value from an instance of ListOfT and stores it in a new buffer, and in memory this List does not have an instance of ListOfT, which is a subclass of List. You need to create a new instance of List that implements ListOfT and save the value correctly.

you can use "Has relationship" and not Is.
   public class ListOfT : IList<string>
   {
       private readonly List<string> Strings = new();

       public ListOfT(List<string> list)
       {
           Strings = list;
       }


       #region IList implemnetions
           //.....

       #endregion

       public ListOfT GenerateSubList()
       {
           return new ListOfT(this.Where(t => t.Contains(".")).ToList());
       }

      
   }


But why inherit from IList<string> then? Your class is still a list

this is part of reequipment to enable to use is like a list or string in this example.

Even if you think it's not for you, I'd like to suggest another route for possible readers that have similar requirements:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
// List of instances, some of which have the property, some do not.
        List<SomeBaseType> list = [new SomeSubType(), 
                                   new SomeSubTypeWP(){SomeProperty="One"},
                                   new SomeSubType(), 
                                   new SomeSubTypeWP(){SomeProperty="Two"},
                                   new SomeSubType(), 
                                   new SomeSubTypeWP(){SomeProperty="Three"}
                                  ];
// Filter and cast all instances that do have the desired property
// and perform some action on them.
        list.OfType<IHasSomeProperty>().Print();
    }
}

// The property for which to filter is defined in an interface
public interface IHasSomeProperty
{
    string SomeProperty {get; set;}
}

public abstract class SomeBaseType
{}

public sealed class SomeSubType : SomeBaseType
{}

// The Subtypes that have the Filter-Property implement above mentioned interface
public sealed class SomeSubTypeWP : SomeBaseType, IHasSomeProperty
{
    public string SomeProperty {get; set;}
}

// We can define extension methods for collections of types having the 
// filtered-for property
public static class ListOfTypesWithSomePropertyExtensions
{
    public static void Print(this IEnumerable<IHasSomeProperty> list)
    {
        foreach(var item in list) Console.WriteLine(item.SomeProperty);
    }
}

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KP3l5c
And that's just one out of many ways to handle this without the need to implement IList<T> or inherit from List<T>.
